# Async call within Conditional in Promise Chain Not Finishing before Progressing

Tags: javascript, if-statement, promise

I have a conditional within my promise chain that runs an async function and prior to the async function completing it assumes that the condition was met and jumps to returning the `else` statement. It might be my lack of understanding the differences between async and promises, but I find it strange that the conditional evaluates that `else if(!user.validPassword(password))` is not met prior to the method completing. The value getting returned is `true` or `false` depending on if the password matches, but even if `false` is returned the body of that `else if` is not run.

Can anyone help me understand what is off in my logic?

**Here is the promise chain with the if conditional:**

```
passport.use(new passportLocal({ 
        passReqToCallback: true,
        usernameField: 'email'
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        console.log('passportLocal Callled')
        console.log(email)
        console.log(password)
        User.findOne({ 
            where: {
                email: email
            }
        }).then(function(user){
            console.log('User.findOne - Finished Query')
            if(!user){
                console.log("User not found")
                // User not found
                return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: 'User does not exist in the database.'});
            } else if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
                console.log("Password is incorrect")
                // Wrong password
                done(null, false, { status: "error", body: "Incorrect Password" });
            } else {
                console.log("User found & password correct")
                // User found and password correct
                return done(null, user, { status: "success", body: "You have successfully signed in!" })
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Server error with signin")
            console.log(err)
            // Server error
            return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: "It looks like there was a server issue. Please try again." });
        })        
    })
);
```

**And the if statement by itself for clarity:**

```
if(!user){
                console.log("User not found")
                // User not found
                return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: 'User does not exist in the database.'});
            } else if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
                console.log("Password is incorrect")
                // Wrong password
                done(null, false, { status: "error", body: "Incorrect Password" });
            } else {
                console.log("User found & password correct")
                // User found and password correct
                return done(null, user, { status: "success", body: "You have successfully signed in!" })
            }
```

**And finally `user.validPassword(password)`:**

```
users.prototype.validPassword = async function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password); // returns `true` or `false`
  }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `async`/`await` but you're not using `await` anywhere?

Comment: Doesn't passport support promises, do you really need to call a `done` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `compareSync`, which is synchronous. The `validPassword` function doesn't need to be async (and shouldn't be, since it creates needless complication and bugs). Async functions always return Promises, and Promises are objects, which are truthy, so the `if` doesn't test what you want.

Change to:

```
users.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
```

Just for the sake of information, if you wanted to use the asynchronous version of `compare`, which returns a Promise, you'd return the Promise for it to be used inside the next `.then`. Or, even better, use `await` to keep the code flat and readable:

```
try {
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
  if(!user){
    console.log("User not found")
    return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: 'User does not exist in the database.'});
  }
  const valid = await user.validPassword(password);
  if (!valid) {
    console.log("Password is incorrect")
    return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: "Incorrect Password" });
  }
  console.log("User found & password correct")
  return done(null, user, { status: "success", body: "You have successfully signed in!" })
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Server error with signin")
  console.log(err)
  // Server error
  return done(null, false, { status: "error", body: "It looks like there was a server issue. Please try again." });
}
```